# Calendar "starts and ends" bug

Tags: calendar, debug, google-calendar, icalendar

A few weeks ago, my calendar started to lose its mind. I've connected my Google Calendar to the iOS one and I also have an automated pull from Facebook Events to Google.

[image]

Basically, doesn't matter what event it is, because it always gets replicated with dummy and annoying "starts and ends" events. I've tried to desync my calendars but it didn't work. Any ideas? Has this happened to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to solve this. It was caused by IFTTT.

I highly recommend anyone to NOT use their calendar [module](https://ifttt.com/applets/jwP9SYut-ios-calendar-events-to-google-calendar).